# Void Method in Service is not Mocking in Integration Testing

Tags: java, testing, mockito, integration, void

In my spring boot project, one of my Service depends on external service like Amazon. I am writing the integration testing of the Controller classes. So, I want to mock the method in the AmazonService class(as it depends on third party API). The method is void with a single Long argument and can throw a **custom application-specific exceptions.**

The method is as follows:-

```
class AmazonService{
public void deleteMultipleObjects(Long enterpriseId) {
        String key = formApplicationLogokey(enterpriseId,null);
        List<S3ObjectSummary> objects = getAllObjectSummaryByFolder(key);
        List<DeleteObjectsRequest.KeyVersion> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.stream().forEach(object->keys.add(new DeleteObjectsRequest.KeyVersion(object.getKey())));
        try{
            DeleteObjectsRequest deleteObjectsRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest(this.bucket).withKeys(keys);
            this.s3client.deleteObjects(deleteObjectsRequest);
            log.debug("All the Application logos deleted from AWS for the Enterprise id: {}",enterpriseId);
        }
        catch(AmazonServiceException e){
            throw new AppScoreException(AppScoreErrorCode.OBJECT_NOT_DELETED_FROM_AWS);
        }
    }}
```

**class Test**

```
class Test
    {
        @Autowired
        AmazonServiceImpl amazonService;

        @Autowired
        EnterpriseService enterpriseService;

        @Before
        public void init()
        {
            amazonService = Mockito.mock(AmazonServiceImpl.class);        
            Mockito.doNothing().when(amazonService).deleteMultipleObjects(isA(Long.class));
        }


        @Test
        public void testDeleteEnterprise(){
            setHeaders();
            EnterpriseDTO enterpriseDTO = createEnterpriseEntity(null,"testDeleteEnterpriseName3",null,null,null);
            String postUrl = TestUrlUtil.createURLWithPort(TestConstants.ADD_ENTERPRISE,port);
            HttpEntity<EnterpriseDTO> request1 = new HttpEntity<>(enterpriseDTO,headers);
            ResponseEntity<EnterpriseDTO> response1 = restTemplate.postForEntity(postUrl,request1,EnterpriseDTO.class);
            assert response1 != null;
            Long enterpriseId = Objects.requireNonNull(response1.getBody()).getId();
            String url = TestUrlUtil.createURLWithPort(TestConstants.DELETE_ENTERPRISE,port)+File.separator+enterpriseId;
            HttpEntity<EnterpriseDTO> request = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
            ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.DELETE,request,Object.class);
            Assert.assertEquals(Constants.ENTERPRISE_DELETION_SUCCESS_MESSAGE,response.getBody());
        }
    }
```

**class EnterpriseResource**

```
class EnterpriseResource
{
    @DeleteMapping("/enterprises/{enterpriseId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteEnterprise(@PathVariable Long enterpriseId) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Enterprise : {}", enterpriseId);
        enterpriseService.delete(enterpriseId);
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(Constants.ENTERPRISE_DELETION_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

**class EnterpriseServiceImpl**

```
class EnterpriseServiceImpl
{
    @Override
    public void delete(Long enterpriseId) {
        log.debug("Request to delete Enterprise : {}", enterpriseId);
        enterpriseRepository.deleteById(enterpriseId);
        amazonService.deleteMultipleObjects(enterpriseId);
    }
}
```

I have tried various approaches to Mock this method but it didn't work and control is going inside this method during debugging. I want to do nothing in this method during testing.
I have tried the various approaches like throw(), doNothing(), spy() etc.

Please help what is missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share how your test looks like? By default all methods on a mocked class do nothing (apart from returning "empty" value).

Comment: I have edit the question and edit the code.

Comment: The code is overwriting AmazonService in the test but the EnterpriseService has still the original version. You can use @MockBean to tell Spring to use mocked version of a component in the test content.